# Android Studio stops responding after placing first UI element

Tags: android, android-studio

The SDK is kind of 'freezed' after I add an element like "TextView". It doesn't say 'Not  Responding' but every button is unclickable, so I have to close it every time using Task Manager. If I minimize AS, then the entire window gets black.

How to fix this?

Comment: You could try re-installing, or maybe buy a new computer.

Comment: What' wrong with you people ? Why did you downvote ? I tried to reinstall and my computer is already decent (i5, GTX770, 8GB RAM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem on my own. Apparently, when you try to insert a text widget on a relative layout, using duplicated "resource id", it causes AS to crash.

You can fix this by simply editing the duplicated id name before doing anything else.